# How to SELECT value Where value = ''another SELECT"

Tags: mysql, select

First of all I searched for correct answer but I didn't find. 
I have a function:

```
SELECT user_email 
FROM `registracija_complete` 
WHERE user_id = (SELECT `id` 
                 FROM `base` 
                 WHERE `sex` = 2 
                   AND gimdat BETWEEN '1973-01-01' AND '1994-12-31');
```

but that function is not working, MySQL says that error is near SELECT id FROM `base

Why I'm getting this error? How to write that function correctly?

Comment: The query appears to be valid SQL syntax. Show us the table definitions (output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE registracija_complete;` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE base;`)

Comment: When MySQL says "error is near" it gives You a selection from query text *starting from the symbol where the problem starts**. Your query text is valid (excluding the subquery may return more than 1 row). Check the text for invalid invisible symbols (CHR(160) instead of space, for example).

Comment: And copy MySQL error message from first to last char there, not only a little part of ot.

Comment: By the way, we don't see any function in the code you posted. Is that at typo and you meant query or is the code a part of the code you use to define a function? If that's the case, please post the whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:

```
SELECT user_email 
FROM `registracija_complete` 
WHERE user_id IN
(
  SELECT `id` 
  FROM `base` 
  WHERE `sex` = 2 
  AND gimdat  BETWEEN '1973-01-01' AND '1994-12-31'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The first (outer) select query expects one value to be returned for `ID` from the second (sub-) select,  but actually the second select is returning more than one `ID` value. That is the issue.

#### Solution

Try to use `IN` instead of `=`.